# Intent or callbacks to know output devices selected when call in progress

Tags: android-11

Steps:

1. Connected wired headset and Bluetooth headset.
2. Receive an incoming call to the device where WHS and BTHS are connected.
3. Accept the call. Switch to different output devices like Speaker, WHS, BTHS.

I am using android 11. When call in progress, we can select different output devices such as Speaker, WHS, and  BTHS. Is there any intent or callback to notify voice call routed to speaker/wired headset/Bluetooth headset?
On hot plug connection/disconnection, events will have listened. Based on the connection/disconnection event, we can perform our operation. But on the soft switch(selecting output devices from call application when call in progress),  do we get any indication that output device for voice call stream got changed, so other applications can listen to intent/callback to carry out my customized operation.

Comment: This is a few months old, and no answers?  I could really use help in getting notifications about changes to audio output (like headsets being plugged in/out as well as bluetooth).  The docs seem to fail on this salient point.